# why tspan instead of class? italics not rendered using htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, rendering, epub

When using `htlatex` with "html,fn-in", the generated html has

```
<tspan font-family="cmti" font-size="10">should be italics </tspan>
```

but this is not rendered in the html (at least not in chrome and safari).

A simple

```
<span class "cmti-10x-x-109">finally italics </span>
```

would work perfectly.

The problem is not really html, but the fact that the epub I generate from that does not render either... using ebook-convert

(I'm using the `memoir` package.)

How should I fix this?

**Edit**
Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% Below just a command to show colors
\newcommand*{\titleTH}{\begingroup
\raggedleft
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
{\large Welcome to}\\[0.167\textheight]
{\Large \bfseries Something}\\[\baselineskip]
{\textcolor{red}{\Huge Red}}\\[\baselineskip]
{\small No reason to be scared\\}\par
\vfill
{QED}\par
\vspace*{3\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
%% Here there was the loading of a picture
\end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

% Commenting out this line would make the following text render right
\titleTH

\newpage

Here I write \textit{the part that should be} italics, \textbf{D'OH!}
```

\end{document}

The problem seems to be the tikz package, as [michal.h21](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2891/michal-h21) suggested.

Comment: this may happen when you use `tikz` and `svg` output. could you please provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tikz` configures lot of things in each picture when it is executed with `tex4ht`. unfortunately, one of these configurations is global and persists even after end of the picture and it is the configuration used for catching font changes.

You can try to use this `.cfg` file to reset this configuration to normal value after end of each tikz picture:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\old@endpicture\pgfsys@endpicture
\def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
  \Configure{htf}{0}{+}{<span\Hnewline%
     class="}{\%s}{-\%s}{x-x-\%d}{}{">}{</span>}%
  \old@endpicture%
}
\makeatother
\EndPreamble
```

run it with

```
htlatex filename cfgname
```

or

```
make4ht -c cfgname.cfg filename
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: @user1919074 this should be maybe also reported to tikz issue tracker, because it is actually quite common problem