# htlatex doesn't notice font change after tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, htlatex

Even a minimal `tikz` picture in my causes `htlatex` not translating commands like `\emph` or `\textbf` if they come after a `tikz` picture.

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\emph{Emphasize}, \textbf{bold},\texttt{typewriter},\textit{italics}  
\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
\emph{Emphasize}, \textbf{bold},\texttt{typewriter},\textit{italics} 

\end{document}
```

Can anybody else verify this bug? I have texlive 2014 as it comes with Fedora 22.

After posting I did some searching and I figured out how to fix the bug:

Create a file called, say, `bugfix.conf` with

```
\Preamble{html}

% Translate \textbf, \textit and \texttt directives into <b>, <em> and <code>
\Configure{emph}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<em>}}{\HCode{</em>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}
\Configure{textit}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<i>}}{\HCode{</i>}}
\Configure{texttt}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<code>}}{\HCode{</code>}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

in it.  Then run htlatex as

```
htlatex file.tex "bugfix.conf"
```

Comment: there was similar question in the past: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257559/2891