# htlatex : lstlisting colors stop after using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, htlatex, lstlisting

Building a tikz figure between two lstlisting scripts remove all the color components of the scripts after the figure. I am using the method listed below (or is there a better way ?).

If I may, does someone know a solution to maintain the color running through the file ?

For instance, using the example from [LaTeX to HTML preserving code coloring from listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64054/latex-to-html-preserving-code-coloring-from-listings) 
with the command

```
htlatex file.tex "xhtml"
```

with file.tex being

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=[Sharp]C,
    keywordstyle=\rmfamily\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\sffamily,
}
\def\mystyle{}

\begin{document}

\Css{div.lstlisting .ectt-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:blue}}
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecss-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:green}} 
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecbx-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:red}}     

{\ttfamily hello}, {\sffamily Hello} {\bfseries Hello}  

\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 10;    
// This is a comment
string str = "hello";
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,xscale=1,yscale=1]
\draw[->,thick] (-1,0)--(3.2,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-1)--(0,3.2) node[above]{$y$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$};
\node[below] at (1,1) {(1;1;0)};
\node[above] at (2.5,1.8) {(2.5;1.8;0)};
\draw[->,thick] (1,1) --(2.5,1.8);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 10;

// This is a comment
string str = "hello";
\end{lstlisting}    

\end{document}
```

leads to

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This issue is caused by TikZ driver for `tex4ht`. It uses the following configuration:

```
\Configure{htf} {0}{+}{<tspan font-family="}{\%s}{" font-size="\%s}{}{}{">}{</tspan>}%
```

This causes following font changing commands to produce `<tspan>` elements, instead of `<span>`, which are used by default in the HTML output. `<tspan>` elements should be used only in the SVG, but this configuration remains active even after end of the TikZ picture. The Css configuration which you use depends on a correct font class name, which isn't produced anymore. This is just one of issues with the default `tex4ht` driver. You can use an [alternative driver](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht), which uses `dvisvgm` for the conversion and it doesn't redefine `tex4ht` configurations, so it doesn't have such side effects.

After installation, it can be used in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
 \fi
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=[Sharp]C,
    keywordstyle=\rmfamily\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\sffamily,
}
\def\mystyle{}

\begin{document}


{\ttfamily hello}, {\sffamily Hello} {\bfseries Hello}  

\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 10;    
// This is a comment
string str = "hello";
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,xscale=1,yscale=1]
\draw[->,thick] (-1,0)--(3.2,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->, thick] (0,-1)--(0,3.2) node[above]{$y$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$};
\node[below] at (1,1) {(1;1;0)};
\node[above] at (2.5,1.8) {(2.5;1.8;0)};
\draw[->,thick] (1,1) --(2.5,1.8);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{lstlisting}
int x = 10;

// This is a comment
string str = "hello";
\end{lstlisting}    

\end{document}
```

The important line is

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
 \fi
```

which declares the new driver. I've also moved the `\Css` commands to a configuration file `myconfig.cfg`, so the TeX file can be compiled using `pdflatex` without errors as well.

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{div.lstlisting .ectt-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:blue}}
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecss-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:green}} 
\Css{div.lstlisting .ecbx-1000 {font-family: monospace;color:red}}     
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The document can be compiled using

```
make4ht -um draft -c myconfig.cfg file.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @michal.h21. Again,you are helpful ! However, I have looked at your explanation and search on internet : in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257559/why-tspan-instead-of-class-italics-not-rendered-using-htlatex you gave also a solution which I tried and .. it works also without having to use some eps file. Isn't it better ?

Comment: So, in pgfsys-tex4ht.def, why not replace
 \Configure{htf} {0}{+}{<tspan font-family="}{\%s}{" font-size="\%s}{}{}{">}{</tspan>}
with  \Configure{htf} {0}{+}{<span\Hnewline class="}{\%s}{-\%s}{x-x-\%d}{}{">}{</span>}% ? 
Does it break something somewhere or if use in an other way ?

Comment: @Jocelyn ah, I forgot about this post. it is another possibility, `dvisvgm` just produces better looking SVG files, so I think that it is preferable. if you don't want to use this alternative driver, don't replace the `htf` configuration, you may get invalid SVG then, `<tspan>` elements are important inside the picture. It just needs to restored back after its end. so you should just use the configuration from the other answer

Comment: @michal.h21Indeed, your svg output is much better with dvisvgm. However, I have tried to do as you said but I have a font problem and more specifically it requires pstoedit (do I really need to use it), and seems not require dvisvgm (which I have) : is it normal ?

Comment: @Jocelyn do you use up to date TeX Live? it should require `dvisvgm` for SVG creation, pstoedit was used in the past

Comment: @michal.h21I use Miktex, and I have dvisgm.exe. I will see if I can update it.

Comment: @Jocelyn I think Miktex should contain this fix as well, I think we communicated with Miktex maintainer about that. There is a package with `tex4ht.env` file in Miktex, so try to update that. It is separated from the main `tex4ht` package.

Comment: It's OK, many packages could be updated, as miktex-dvisvgm-bin-x64-2.9, and now it works. thanks again for you time !

Comment: @Jocelyn nice, we update tex4ht quite often, so it is good to keep your distribution updated as well, as these are mostly bug fixes